# A contest-math inequality: $(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2 \geq \frac{100abc}{a+b+c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, contest-math, maxima-minima

I completed my steps like this:

Let's prove our last inequality:

> $$a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 \geq 40 a b c $$
>
> Let, $$m=\frac ba, \qquad n=\frac ca$$
>
> We have $$m^3+3m^2+3m+1+12n^2+5n+5m^2n+12mn^2+8n^3 \geq40 mn$$
>
> Then,
>
> $$m^3+3m^2+3m+1+12n^2+5n+5m^2n+12mn^2+8n^3=(m^3+8n^3+1)+(5n+5mn^2)+(3m^2+12n^2)+(3m+12mn^2) \geq 40mn$$
>
> Finally we get,
>
> $$\color {red} {\begin{cases}  m^3+8n^3+1 \thinspace \geq \thinspace  6mn \\ 5n+5mn^2\thinspace  \geq \thinspace 10mn \\ 3m^2+12n^2 \thinspace \geq \thinspace  12mn \\ 3m+12mn^2 \thinspace  \geq \thinspace  12mn \end{cases}}\color {red}{\Longrightarrow} \\ \\ \\ \color{blue}
> \Longrightarrow  \color{blue} {\boxed{m^3+3m^2+3m+1+12n^2+5n+5m^2n+12mn^2+8n^3 \geq 40 mn}} $$
>
> Equality only holds for $m=1$ and $n=\dfrac 12$.

### **Q.E.D.**

> If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers prove that the following inequality and find the equality condition.
>
> $$(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2 \geq \frac{100abc}{a+b+c}$$

This inequality was presented to the students on a official paper. I will write my attempts very short.

$$(a+b+c)((a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2)-100abc \geq 0 \\
2 (a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 - 40 a b c + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3) \geq 0 \\
a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 \geq 40 a b c \\$$

We have,

$$a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 \geq \\ \geq 9 \sqrt[9]{a^3 \times 3 a^2 b \times 5 a^2 c \times 3 a b^2 \times 12 a c^2 \times b^3 \times 5 b^2 c \times 12 b c^2 \times 8 c^3}= \\ =9 \times (2^7 \times 3^4 \times 5^2 )^{\frac 19}\times abc\approx 35.955 abc \leq 40 abc $$

In other words,

$$\text{min} \left[  \frac {a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3}{  a b c} \right]=9\times \sqrt[9]{259200} \approx 35.955 \leq40 $$

Comment: See [Hong Kong 2001 Test 1 Q4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h329), also see [Find the minimum $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763739/find-the-minimum-k)

Comment: How did you calculate the min = $9\times \sqrt[9]{259200}$.  THe minimum value will occur if $a^3 = 3a^2b = 5a^2c = 3ab^2=b^3=5b^2c=12bc^2 = 8c^3$ which may not happen.  In fact it is clear it *never* happens.  $a=b$ but $5b = 12c$ but $8c^3 = b^3$?  Can't happen.

Comment: @fleablood yes I wrote it in the comment then I deleted it. Yeah, I  noticed that. Variables are not independent

Comment: @fleablood I think learning my mistake was more important than solving the question

Comment: I agree.  It was a *very* informative dead end.  And can probably be modified to get that the *very* closest the nine terms can get to each other $a^3 \approx b^3 \approx 3a^2b \approx 5a^2c \approx 12bc^2$ will be at a point where the min is $40$, not $35.995$.  I'd bet anything, Mike Rozenberg's answer (which I haven't gone over) finds that exact case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've proven that $a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 \geq 35.955 abc$.

But you have not proven that $35.955abc \le a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 < 40 abc$ need ever occur.

For  $a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 5 a^2 c + 3 a b^2 + 12 a c^2 + b^3 + 5 b^2 c + 12 b c^2 + 8 c^3 = 35.955 abc$ can *only* occur if:

$a^3 = a^2 b =5 a^2 c = 3 a b^2 = 12 a c^2= b^3 = 5 b^2 c = 12 b c^2= 8 c^3$ which is easy to show *never* occurs.  [ If this occurs then $a=b$ and $12c=5b$ and $8c^3 = b^3$ so $8=\frac {12}{5}^3=(2\frac 25)^3$.  ... Never occurs.  ]

Remember the AM-GM theorem which says $A+B+C+ ... + I \ge 9\sqrt[9]{ABC....I}$ has equality holding only if $A=B =C=D.... =I$.  If that equality *can* not hold, that $A+B+C_ ... + I$ must be *strictly* greater than $9\sqrt[9]{ABC....I}$ and proving $A+B+C+.... + I\ge 9\sqrt[9]{ABC....I}$ does *not* contradict $A+B+C+.... + I\ge K\sqrt[9]{ABC....I}$ for $K > 9$.

Comment: Well it's easy to see with powers of $2$.  Proof of AM-GM if $n = 2$:   $a+ b \ge 2\sqr{ab}\iff a -2\sqrt{ab} +b \ge 0\iff (\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \ge 0$.  The last statement is *always* true.  But equality *only* holds if $a=b$. You can get some near variations.

Answer (score 7):

To demonstrate the inequality is wrong, all you need is a counterexample ... so given your analysis, can you come up with one? That should show it pretty quickly.

Comment: The question title was wrong. I fixed I`m sorry.

Comment: After question's edit by OP, I guess this is no longer a counterexample...

Comment: @Elvin Ah!  OK, the basic point still stands though: why don't you come up with some concrete values of $a,b,c$? Given your analysis, that should be possible, no?

Comment: I got a little excited. That's why I wrote the question title wrong. I just didn't believe there was a mistake on an official paper. Do you think my analysis is correct?

Answer (score 5):

I think your inequality is right.

Let $c=x\sqrt{ab}.$

Thus, by AM-GM
$$((a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2)(a+b+c)\geq(4ab+(2\sqrt{ab}+4c)^2)(2\sqrt{ab}+c).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$(4+(2+4x)^2)(2+x)\geq100x$$ or
$$(2x-1)^2(x+4)\geq0$$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

theres another way i found which matches equality.

$(a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2 \geq \frac{100abc}{a+b+c}$

By multiplying both side by a+b+c

$$2(a^2+b^2+8c^2+2ab+4bc+4ca)(a+b+c) \geq 100abc$$
Proving this is equivalence to proving $(a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2 \geq \frac{100abc}{a+b+c}$

By AM-GM

$$2(a^2+b^2+4c^2+4c^2+ab+ab+2bc+2bc+2ca+2ca) \geq 20\sqrt[10]{2^8a^6b^6c^8} = 20\sqrt[5]{2^4a^3b^3c^4}  $$
on the other side,
$$\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+c \geq 5\sqrt[5]{\frac{a^2b^2c}{2^4}}$$
By multiplying these 2 inequalities,
$$2(a^2+b^2+4c^2+4c^2+ab+ab+2bc+2bc+2ca+2ca)(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+c )\geq 100\sqrt[5]{a^5b^5c^5} = 100abc$$
The equality is when a = b = 2c

### **Q.E.D.**